# Sequel Pro closes Laravel Homestead SSH session

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, homestead, sequelpro

Ever since upgrading to the newest version of Laravel Homestead (v0.4.0), I'm having a weird issue where when I try to log in to Sequel Pro, it disconnects my Homestead SSH and does not let me back in unless I do `vagrant suspend` followed by `vagrant up`.

The error message it gives me is:

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed by remote host.
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
```

And when I then try and login via Sequel Pro I get the following error message:

```
Connection Failed!
Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1, or the request timed out.

Be sure that the address is correct and that you have the necessary privileges, or try increasing the connection timeout (currently 10 seconds).

MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)
```

My Sequel Pro settings are:

```
Name: Homestead
Host: 127.0.0.1
Username: homestead
Password: secret
Port: 33060
```

Worth referencing I have setup Sequel Pro as per this post here: http://www.tannerhearne.com/using-sequel-pro-laravel-homestead/

Comment: This is strange, however maybe you should try in `Sequel Pro` connecting via SSH host?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek it does the same thing. Very odd. I'm going to try completely removing Homestead and installing again.

Comment: Even with a fresh install, it does the same thing.

Comment: Ok, and If you don't connect via `Sequel Pro` is it working fine? For SSH in `Sequeal Pro` which port do you use for connectin to mysql - is it `3306` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually solved this by using the following `Sequel Pro` settings:

```
Host: 192.168.10.10
Username: Homestead
Password: secret
Port: 3306
```

where 192.168.10.10 is the IP address of my vagrant box.

It seems the new Homestead update (`v0.4.0`) rendered my previous settings, useless.